# Checkout two git repositories through jekins under same workspace in two different folders

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have two git repositories and trying to checkout from Multiple SCM Jenkins plugin but it is checkout only single repositories.

Can someone let me know how we can achieve this?

Checkout two different git repositories under same workspace

http://txy.ts.tho.com/aegAndDS/md5.git

http://txy.ts.tho.com/aegAndDS/or.git

This first one should go to md5 folder and next one should go to or folder under same workspace

NOTE:I know we can do it through multiple jobs but I want to know is it possible from single job?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am able to find the answer and able to checkout the two different git repositories under same workspace in different folders

[image]